# Hiding Retention Label on SP Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, retention-policy

I have enabled the Microsoft Compliance Center's retention policy, mainly for our document library. However, every time we create a new record in the SharePoint list, a field called "Apply label" is added. Is there any chance I can hide or remove this column?

I have checked the list settings and other locations, and I can't see or find this column.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, when we Create Retention Labels and apply Retention Policies to sites the retention labels and when we choose option” All location or choose specific location ” it will apply to all SharePoint online document library and in list items as well.

Unfortunately, I'm afraid there is no way to remove label only for list item in SharePoint online. I would suggest posting a uservocie here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products. What's more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Allen that there is no solution OOB however if you are okay with custom spfx extensions - you can build an extension which can hide the Apply label row using css for a specific list or all lists depending on the URL. We have done something similar in our Online tenant and it works so far.

Comment: Hi Chandan, I have little bid of experience, however can you please share more details of your solution?

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/) and implement a javascript code that hides that column for you as soon as the details pane open. You can look for div with class="ReactFieldEditor-core--display" with aria-label="Apply Label" and then hide its parent or remove it altogether from the html